# How to make jQuery dialog modal?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I am using jQuery dialog in asp.net. It is working fine for me. The problem is when I open the dialog box, I can still work parent page functionality. I don't want that. Just dialog to modal and should not allow focus on parent page.

```
window.onload = function onloadFunction() {

        //setup edit person dialog
     $('#uploadPic').dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
             draggable: true,
             title: "Upload Picture",
             open: function(type, data) {
                 $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
             }
         });
     }
```

Is there any way to make it modal? Or if lost focus on dialog box close it automatically?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use

```
$('#uploadPic').dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true,
         draggable: true,
         title: "Upload Picture",
         open: function(type, data) {
             $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
         }
     });
 }
```

I have just added the modal option to your sample.

Comment: Check out the documentation on this option here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-modal

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of JQuery Ui Dialog in: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Exist a Option called Modal, here is some samples from doc:

Initialize a dialog with the modal option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ modal: true });
```

Get or set the modal option, after init.

```
//getter
var modal = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "modal" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "modal", true );
```

Comment: setting the dialog modal after init does not work for me